# Create a graph from a data table

Tags: graph-theory

A car rental company is developing a fleet renewal plan for the next four years. It has been decided that newly acquired vehicles must be replaced after a minimum of one year of use or a maximum of three. The replacement costs in Euros are indicated in the following table.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnEr4.png)

They ask me to make the corresponding graph of this problem. So what I can understand is that the years would be the nodes of my graph but I don't know how the connections between these nodes would be.

To give more context to my question I am going to show an example of a graph

[Example of a graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qG0mO.png)

Comment: Are you sure they are asking about the combinatorial graph with nodes and connections? I would assume it’s the graph with X and Y axes, i.e. a chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a digraph where edge from year $y_1$ to $y_2$ means the car acquired in year $y_1$ is replaced in the year $y_2$. And label the edges with the costs. Something like this:

[image]

This would make sense, since now they can for example find the shortest path from 2022 to 2026 and thus minimize their costs of car replacements.

---

*I'll just store the Sage-code I used in the generation of that image here*

```
g = DiGraph()
g.add_edge(2022, 2023, label=4000)
g.add_edge(2023, 2024, label=4300)
g.add_edge(2024, 2025, label=4800)
g.add_edge(2025, 2026, label=4900)

g.add_edge(2022, 2024, label=5400)
g.add_edge(2023, 2025, label=6200)
g.add_edge(2024, 2026, label=7100)

g.add_edge(2022, 2025, label=9800)
g.add_edge(2023, 2026, label=8700)


show(g.plot(vertex_size=1450, edge_labels=True))
print(g.shortest_path(2022, 2026, by_weight=True, weight_function=lambda e: e[2]))
```